# puppeteer-2.1.1 with latest version not working for proxy

Tags: node.js

```
    Running puppeteer with Proxy Authorization failing.

    Puppeteer version: 2.1.1

    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    // Function to call proxy url
    (async () => {
        try {`enter code here`
          let data = [];
          let options = {
            headless: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            slowMo: 134,
            devtools: true,
            args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--window-size=1920x1200',
            '--proxy-server=proxy.crawlera.com:8010',// proxy url
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list'
            ]
          }

          const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
          let page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
          await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1200 });
          const key = '<My API Key>:';
          await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
              'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(key).toString('base64'),
          });
```

var res =  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 0});

```
          return [];
        } catch (e) {
          return e;
        }
    })();
```

Above is working for puppeteer version 1.18.0 , but failing and giving below error for version 2.1.1
Error: net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

Answer (score 1):

For some reason "Proxy-Authorization" among other headers (like HOST) is prohibited to be set in newer versions of chromium and puppeteer

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/3611052c055897e5ebbc5b73ea295092e0c20141/services/network/public/cpp/header_util_unittest.cc#L75

Use old software version without such restrictions, e.g.
Puppeteer 1.17 with bundled Chromium 76.x